# Populate dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/br918p0w/
I am trying to populate a dropdown in a class button (custom dropdown) and I cannot seem to get the JavaScript to populate this dropdown. When I click three the dropdown should say three.

```
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">1</a>
    <a href="#about">2</a>
    <a href="#contact">3</a>
```

Comment: add more explanation to this question

Comment: alright. i did. basically that works and shows the dropdown without their being append but I need to populate the drop down when i click it..

Comment: firstly your html in question is invalid no one can help you with that kind of effort in making a good question. im sorry i dont really see any effort here. this is not a make me my code site

Comment: alright, where's the jQuery code?

Comment: I have it in the fiddle @JohannesJander, why won't the append work when I click a dropdown option?

Answer (score 1):

Don't give Enter/line break between append code in JQuery.

Make it like:

```
$this.append('<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content"><a href="#home">1</a><a href="#about">2</a><a href="#contact">3</a></div>');
```

not:

```
$this.append('
     <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#home">1</a>
    <a href="#about">2</a>
    <a href="#contact">3</a>
  </div>

    ');
```

And include JQuery plugins.

**Note:** Put css in css section in JSFiddle

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/br918p0w/2/)**

Comment: for some reason it is not replacing the dropdown with "1" when i click "1" or "2" when i click "2"  isnt that what focus is for?

Comment: @WillW-TrainGao It is because you are trying to append inside button. instead append to parent. ` $this.parent().append('<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content"><a href="#home">1</a><a href="#about">2</a><a href="#contact">3</a></div>');` https://jsfiddle.net/br918p0w/3/